# Can't get IF statement to work when comparing strings

Tags: php

I'm trying a rather simple test, using an HTML checkbox, where a user can select up to four items (foods in my test).  The selected items are passed to a PHP script, where I check them against the selected items to determine what the user chose.

Based on that, I use if statements to determine what the user selected, and write a binary value into an array for future processing (that's the next project to tackle).

My problem is that I can't get the `if` statements to ever become true.  As you can see from the code, I used `trim` to strip off any excess characters, and used `var_dump` and `print` commands to see what I had prior to entering the set of `if` statements.

All seems a-ok up to that point, but the `if` statements are never true (I put echo statements inside of each to tell me that).  Below is the segment of the code in question, and the output of the PHP script, when I selected all four food items.  I'd sure appreciate any insight.

ps - I also tried `strcmp` in lieu of IF statements, to no avail.

The PHP:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($userChecked ); $i++) {

 // var_dump to show what exactly was passed

 trim($userChecked[$i]);

 var_dump($userChecked[$i]);

 print "<pre>[".$userChecked[$i]."]</pre>";

// now go through each checked item to see where the match is
// echo that we have a match and set the corresponding array value to 1

 if ($userChecked[i]=="soup") {
   echo  "the user wants soup<br />";
   $pref_array[0] = '1';
 }

 if ($userChecked[i]=="salad") {
   echo  "the user wants salad<br />";
   $pref_array[1] = '1';
 }

if ($userChecked[i]=="cheese") {
   echo  "the user wants cheese<br />";
   $pref_array[2] = '1';
 }

if ($userChecked[i]=="sardines") {
   echo  "the user wants sardines<br />";
   $pref_array[3] = '1';
 }

 }
```

The output when the all checkboxes are selected (soup, salad, cheese, sardines):

string(4) "soup"
[soup]
string(5) "salad"
[salad]
string(6) "cheese"
[cheese]
string(8) "sardines"
[sardines]

Comment: You want $userChecked[$i] not [i] - i isn't a constant defined in scope. Turn on error reporting and you'll figure these kind of errors out much faster :)

Comment: @Martin Sharp eyes. :)

Comment: Maybe it's better to compare strings with http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Answer (score 4):

`$userChecked[i]` would not give you the output since i is not the index of the array or key of the array. So you have to use `$userChecked[$i]` instead

Comment: Thank you very much!  That made the IF statements work as they were supposed to.  Thanks also for the quick response.  - Dave